# Issue in hosting a webapplication in a local machine

Tags: apache, tomcat, localhost

I have developed a webapplication in my local machine. the application is hosted on tomcat 7.0.22 server. the application is accessed using http://localhost:8080/app

When i use this in my localmachine, I am not facing any problems. But when I intend to share the link with my fellow team mates using the links http://myipaddress:8080/app, I am getting Javascript errors. I placed the js files in the build path of the application.

Even i have noticed the tables width are changed in the same browser

I am unable to find the problem. Can any one help

Thanks,
Vamsi

Comment: where is the IP or hostname in your address?

Comment: Check to make sure you haven't hard coded the paths with "localhost".

Comment: i have edited the question and i havent harcoded any paths as localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing on your own machine, use your own IP instead of "localhost" and should be able to compare apples with apples and avoid confusing cause and effect.

I would say to check the configuration of your host or vhost files, but if all included JS files are on the same host, that is unlikely to be the problem.

My guess is that you hard coded a path somewhere or that the problem is related to some other difference between testing from your machine and their machine (different browser, versions, plugins, etc) and not actually related at all to the domain. Could possibly also be a file permission problem (but that is a wild guess).